# Mover o rato, e saber que estou em cima de um objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma imagem em SVG e quando estiver com o rato por cima da imagem fazer um alert e alterar o cursor para o cursor do hyperlink. Como posso fazer isso?

```
<svg>
  <image /> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

### HTML

```
<svg class="element">
  <image /> 
</svg>
```

### CSS

```
.element:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o evento **onmouseover** disponível em componentes SVG

**SVG**

```
<svg>
  <image onmouseover="alert('Isso é um alert');"/> 
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
 #svg-image:hover { cursor: pointer }
```

Answer (score -2):

Através da utilização do jQuery, tens a função onHover. Basicamente tem de fazer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("image").hover(function(){
        $(this).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
        console.log("Estou em cima da imagem");
        }
    );
});
```